# image moves when hover on - issue with the border

Tags: html, css

Below is the code

**HTML**

```
<div class="fgimg">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fgimg {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
-webkit-border-radius: 150px;
-moz-border-radius: 150px;
background: url('https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2669/5830411257_b21bf9e931_b.jpg') no-repeat;
margin-left:30%;
margin-top:10px;
background-position: center center;
}
.fgimg:hover {
cursor:pointer;
border-radius: 210px;
border-color:#226fa3;
border:outset;
-webkit-border-radius: 150px;
-moz-border-radius: 150px;
```

}

**Here is the demo :**
http://jsfiddle.net/sathish_opr/03kkqywy/1/

When we hover on the image, image position changes.

I would like to see the border color of the image when hovered on, but image position changes automatically :(

what could be the problem ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/03kkqywy/3/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You either set an invisible border on the image in the normal state:

```
border: 3px outset transparent;
```

Or you could apply:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

This way, the border is calculated to the inside of the width and height. (the 200px width for example)

DEMO TIME:
http://jsfiddle.net/03kkqywy/4/

BTW:
you don't need any prefixing on border-radius anymore.
But if you do, allways put the non prefix property as the last one of those.

Answer (score 3):

**Now Define your**

```
.fgimg{
border: solid 3px transparent;
}
```

> [**Demo Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/03kkqywy/2/)

Comment: Hi Azad, could you please have a look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34478943/difficulty-adding-object-as-innerhtml-to-a-dynamically-created-div-in-javascript ?

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you haven't set a border to the image initially. When you hover, the border is added to the overall width of the image and hence you can see it ***move***.

Set a transparent border to the image initially. This way the border is already added o the width of the image and the image won't be ***moving*** when you hover over it.

```
.fgimg{
    border:outset;
    border-color: transparent;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sathish_opr/03kkqywy/1/

Answer (score 1):

css code

```
.fgimg {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
    background: url('https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2669/5830411257_b21bf9e931_b.jpg') no-repeat;
    margin-left:30%;
    margin-top:10px;
    background-position: center center;
    border: solid 3px transparent;
}
.fgimg:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
    border-radius: 210px;
    border-color:#226fa3;
    border:outset;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
}
```

url http://jsfiddle.net/03kkqywy/3/[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/03kkqywy/3/)