# Difficulty adding object as innerHTML to a dynamically created div in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below code in my project

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="Num">
<input type="button" value="Insert Div" onClick="insertDiv(getElementById('Num').value)" />
<div class="container">
<div id="main">All starts from here</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
lookupdata=[
{"id":2,"st":[{"label":"Audi","value":10},{"label":"BMW","value":70}]},
{"id":16,"st":[{"label":"Benz","value":40},{"label":"BMW","value":20}]},
{"id":8,"st":[{"label":"AUDI","value":60},{"label":"Tesla","value":70}]},
{"id":5,"st":[{"label":"MZ","value":30},{"label":"Honda","value":40}]}
];

function insertDiv(Num){
    var ar1=Num.replace('[', '');
    ar1=ar1.replace('[', '');
    ar1=ar1.replace(']', '');
    ar1=ar1.replace(']', '');
    alert(ar1);
    var array = JSON.parse("[" + ar1 + "]");
    alert(JSON.stringify(lookupdata,null,2));
    var i=0;
        for(i;i<array.length;i++)
        {
            $( "<div id='sp"+array[i]+"'>This is div with id "+array[i]+"<div class='st'></div></div>" ).insertAfter( "#main");
        }
}
```

Using above code, I can create div dynamically for the input string array -
Example: If I input [[8,2,5]], it creates three div with id's - 8,2,5

However, I would like to insert st value from the object named 'lookupdata' into the respective id div.

The purpose of this is, I want to use st as input to a chart within the inner div (with class 'st').

How can I do that?

Here is the working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/sathish_panduga/3581rh71/7/

Comment: do a `console.log(array[i])` in your code to see what is there?

Comment: Hi Nikos, it gives the value from the array as  per given index

Comment: Given a id in the lookup array, do you want to iterate through the "st" array to populate them into divs with the same class "st"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) function which is intended for searching an array.

```
function getObjContents(i){
  var arr = $.grep(input, function(e){ 
    return e.id == i; 
  });
  var str="";
  for (var i = 0; i < arr[0].st.length; i++) {
    str += JSON.stringify(arr[0].st[i]);
  }
  return str;
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
$( "<div id='sp"+array[i]+"'>This is div with id "+array[i]+getObjContents(Num)+"<div class='st'></div></div>" ).insertAfter( "#main");
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3581rh71/9/)